# Why does my iPad automatically capitalise Bono but not the edge?

Tags: ios

Can anyone please tell me why my iPad automatically capitalises "Bono" but not "the edge"?

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't get Larry Mullen jr right either — it capitalizes Larry Mullen but not the Jr., and it doesn't auto-add the comma. Adam Clayton comes out just fine.

Comment: @DanielLawson but everyone knows they're not *really* in the band anyways so that's okay. :)

Answer (score 9):

English is hard.

One is easily distinguishable as a [proper noun](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/propernoun.htm). Bono is not a common word that would be anything other than a name. Like Sally or Andreas. The OS can capitalize occurrences of Bono with a high degree of confidence that you were referring to a proper noun.

The other is not easily distinguishable as a proper noun. There is no way to tell if the sentence:

> I played guitar near the edge

is referring to you playing guitar near a [precipice](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Aprecipice) or near another human who has the legal name Dave Evans.

You can create a text shortcut to automatically expand a text snippet you enter like `tedge` to `The Edge` if you like. You can find shortcuts in the Settings app under `General > Keyboards > Shortcuts`.

Comment: I think you just answered this conundrum pro bono.

Comment: Weird, I found that shortcut had automatically downloaded to my phone...